# initial time in Django form does not update

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-forms

I have a class like this in Django forms

```
class DateForm(forms.Form):
to_date = forms.DateTimeField(
    label='To Date',
    input_formats=[settings.API_DATEFORMAT],
    widget=forms.DateTimeInput(
        attrs={
            'placeholder': 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss',
            'class': 'form-control',
        }
    ),
    required=True,
    initial=datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'),
)
```

However, the initial time is not being updated when I use this form in Django views. Looks like the time at which the server is started is cached. Any suggestions how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should not do that. You should pass the initial as a callable; here you can use `datetime.now` without the parentheses. You do not need to pass it to `strftime` at all; the field already takes care of converting from a datetime to a string in the expected format.

Comment: However, when I use just `datetime.now`, the field is recognized as builtin_function_or_method and not as a string